# Xamarin Studio: Why all the whitespace in Debug.WriteLine() output after update?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I output a lot of information by way of Debug.WriteLine() when programming in Xamarin.iOS.  But with the latest version of Xamarin Studio (4.0.10 (build 7)) there is now a ton of whitespace and duplicate output text when I use Debug.WriteLine().

[image]

Is there a way that I can suppress all this extra output, or at least have a little more control over it?  Using Console.WriteLine() solves the problem, but I would prefer to use Debug.WriteLine() so that it is removed from the release build.

Comment: Is this on device or in the simulator?

Comment: It is the same on a device and in the simulator.

Comment: It seems to be Debug.WriteLine which causes it, Console.WriteLine works just fine.

Comment: Rolf, you're right.  But the reason I like to use Debug.WriteLine over Console.WriteLine is all the Debug stuff is removed in the release build.  My worry is that Console.WriteLine, which it is left in the release build (I believe), will be unnecessarily taking up resources.

Comment: Yeah, I was just reporting my findings. I suggest you file a bug (http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) and see if it can be fixed. As far as I know there's no way to configure Xamarin Studio to get the old behavior back.

Comment: Did you ever file a bug for this? I would like to CC to it.

Comment: I did file a bug report: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_activity.cgi?id=13924

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late, but I had already logged a bug for this - still unresolved.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13538

Comment: You did beat me with your bug report by about two weeks.